# Atom style/font in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, fonts, atom-editor

I would like to have the same style from Atom in Eclipse, the color theme is not the problem, one can find it at http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ but the major problem is the font, I've tried Mononoki, Monospace, Monaco, Incolsolata, RobotoMono but non of them looks like the Atom font.

I am using Atom on Ubuntu.
When I try to look on the settings, the font-type or font-family field is empty and font-size is supposedly 14pt, but when I set the font-size in Eclipse to 14pt, then it is very huge, can't be.

[Picture: This is the font I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE6M3.png)